# Formula to transpose horizontal numeric data vertical in excel

Tags: excel

My input data in column A

```
1
2
3
4
5
6 
7 
8
9
```

If I want the above in Column B C D like

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use INDEX with some math:

```
=INDEX($A:$A,(ROW($A1)-1)*3+COLUMN(A$1))
```

Put in B1 copy over 3 columns and down 3 rows.

The `*3` is the number of columns desired.

[image]

Comment: Sir in the above example if I want to extend the with more horizontal data what to do, in this example if I want to transpose to 6 column will it come like this 1 2 3 4 5 6 in B1 c1 D1... And 7 8 9 in b2 c2 d2

Comment: If you want to extend it to 6 columns then you need to change the `*3` to `*6`

Comment: Thank you very much sir much obliged

Comment: please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: Sir one confusion suppose there is 1500 quantity of numeric digit like above and if I want to spread in 25 rows, then it will be 60 columns, for this what to do please help sir

Comment: I mean number of rows and number of columns are different , in this 25 rows and 60 columns

Comment: Then change the `*3` to `*60` and copy over 60 columns and down 25 rows.